# How do I run a line through an array using a for loop

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChangeMaker {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the total cost");
        int cost = console.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the total amount paid");
        int paid = console.nextInt();
    }

    public static void makeChange(int paid, int cost) {
        int[] billDenomination = { 2000, 1000, 500, 100 };
        int[] coinDenomination = { 25, 10, 5, 1 };
        int remainder = (paid - cost);

        for (int remainder = 0 // TODO
    }
}
```

How do I run int remainder through the for loop so that it returns the values of the denominations?

Comment: You might start with `while (remainder > 0) {` and loop over `billDenomination` - check if a denomination is less than remainder, and if so subtract from `remainder`. Then do the same with `coinDenomination`. So two inner loops. Best of luck!

Comment: while (remainder > 0)
        {
         if (billDenomination< remainder);
         
        }

Comment: its saying that bad operand types because first type is int[] and second type is int

Comment: whats the relation between billDenomination & CoinDenomination

Comment: The ammount of change is supposed to be measured in bills and then once it gets to small for bills its supposed to give coins

Comment: loop over `billDenomination`: `for (int bill : billDenomination) { while (bill < remainder) { System.out.println(bill); remainder -= bill; } }` - you'll need another loop for coins. Hence **two *inner* loops**.